# store userId in session_id()

Tags: php, session

*(I was looking some tips for php session security but in my total ignorance I miss lot of basic things. I'm doing a very basic web game without login but I need to store session)*

If is safe store `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;` ...

Is not safe, then, store **userId** in **session_id** like `session_id(userId)` when all players knows other users Id? If not, what is the diference?

Comment: Don't use `session_id` to store user data. That is not what it is for. Session data is stored on the server, so using `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE` is as safe as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe, not.

But it depends on the context. Of course, it has nothing to do with $_COOKIE['logged_in']=true, which, for sure, is unsafe.

But the following is unsafe too

```
 session_id($user_id);
 $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
```

Because session_id will be stored in a cookie, and this way you can forge another user_id.

You have to remember that Session variables are stored on the server, and cookie in the browser. So if you consider your server as a self place, it is safe, as long as you can't forge your identification cookies to fake your session.

Comment: Ok then, the diference is session_id() is a **COOKIE** and not a **SESSION** key.